# A PHP equivalent for a VB.NET password hash function

Tags: php, vb.net, hash, passwords, sha256

I have the following Visual Basic .NET function that is used to generate password hashes that are stored in an internal database:

```
Public Function HashPassword(ByVal Password As String, ByVal Salt As String) As String
    Dim pwd As String = Password & Salt
    Dim hasher As New Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed()
    Dim pwdb As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd)
    Dim pwdh As Byte() = hasher.ComputeHash(pwdb)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(pwdh)
End Function
```

I need help creating a PHP equivalent of the above function:

**Example:**

```
Assuming a password string of: warn
A salt value of: i<|Xf":n_y_Yr"Lor`qAA].QK(2C8AJ:Z"\f&TC7bi=Acw_.w|
The returned hash should be: 0Yq3gR09U1GKfFRzmRxdJXK5jSQowHp/YLGA88p0s18=
```

I'm having trouble replicating the hash in PHP.

Kind Regards,

Voxinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first links in google :(

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php with sha256
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

```
$pwd = 'warn';
$salt = 'i<|Xf":n_y_Yr"Lor`qAA].QK(2C8AJ:Z"\f&TC7bi=Acw_.w|';
$pwd .= $salt;
$r1 = hash('sha256', $pwd, true); // binary hash
$r2 = base64_encode($r1); // base64 representation
echo $r2;
```

output

```
0Yq3gR09U1GKfFRzmRxdJXK5jSQowHp/YLGA88p0s18=
```

Comment: I spent *no joke* two hours toying with this and researching on google with no luck reproducing the hash. Thank you very much for the courtesy!

Comment: Good job IIya. You were a minute fast !

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
private static function hash($string) {
    $result = '';
    if (substr($string, 0, 1) == '#')
        $result = $string;
    else {
        $result = '#' . hash('sha256', $string);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

You can just pass the user-provided password, or even an already hashed password as it will detect if already hashed or not. Of course this presumes that passwords starting with a `#`hash character are not allowed (and would be caught before).

Answer (score 0):

To hash passowrds, i'm currently using a function similar to:

```
function hashPassword($str, $salt='786df') {
    hash('sha512', $salt.$str.'7');
}
```

This is a SH512 with a dynamic salt (per site) and a fixed salt (to have a salt if $salt is empty that is a php constant in fact). This solution is ultra secure, I understand it made hashes that are very hard to decrypt.

Like you did, you can use SHA256 by this way and then use base64_encode() (probably useless).