# Equivalent password hash function for vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net, encoding

In my web application, before insert password in db, I create a random salt, and later I pass this  salt to an hash function, like this:

```
function generate_salt()
{
   $max_length = 100;
   $salt = hash('sha256', (uniqid(rand(), true)));
   return substr($salt, 0, $max_length);
}

function hash_password($salt, $password)
{
    $half = (int)(strlen($salt) / 2);
    $hash = hash('sha256', substr($salt, 0, $half ) . $password . substr($salt, $half));

    for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    {
        $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
    }

    return $hash; 
}
```

This is my `vb.net` function:

```
Public Shared Function CreateRandomSalt() As String

    Dim mix As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+=][}{<>"
    Dim salt As String = ""
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For i As Integer = 1 To 100 'Lunghezza del salt
        Dim x As Integer = rnd.Next(0, mix.Length - 1)
        salt &= (mix.Substring(x, 1))
    Next

    Return salt

End Function

Public Shared Function Hash512(password As String, salt As String) As String

    Dim convertedToBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password & salt)
    Dim hashType As HashAlgorithm = New SHA512Managed()
    Dim hashBytes As Byte() = hashType.ComputeHash(convertedToBytes)
    Dim hashedResult As String = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes)
    Return hashedResult

End Function
```

Now my problem's that when I create a new user or update a password for a specific user from my `vb.net` app, the web application can't execute the login to my user, maybe the password encoding is diffent, so I need a function for `vb.net` or `php` that allow me to have the same encoding. How I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A PHP equivalent for a VB.NET password hash function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457726/a-php-equivalent-for-a-vb-net-password-hash-function)

Comment: But I have an encoding of 256

Comment: Do you store the salt or are you generating a random one everytime the user tries to log?

Comment: I store the salt as UNIQUE in my db, I have two database one for client app and another for web app.

Comment: In that case, your problem isn't in the salt function. It's in the hash512 function. Your two hash functions are completely different. One put the password in the middle of the salt, the other just appends it. In one function you hash 100000 times, while the other you do it just once.

Comment: So which edit suggest?

Answer (score -2):

Create Md5 password:

```
Public Function MD5(ByVal pass As String) As String
        Try
            Dim MD5p As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
            Dim baytlar As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass)
            Dim hash As Byte() = MD5p.ComputeHash(baytlar)
            Dim kapasite As Integer = (hash.Length * 2 + (hash.Length / 8))
            Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(kapasite)
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To hash.Length - 1
                sb.Append(BitConverter.ToString(hash, I, 1))
            Next I
            Return sb.ToString().TrimEnd(New Char() {" "c})
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "0"
        End Try
    End Function
```

Insert or Control : `MD5(Password String)`

Comment: How this could help me?